# Airflow cross DAGs dependency daily task depends on hourly task

Tags: airflow

I would like to find a good way to achieve cross DAGs dependency in airflow with different scheduling frequency. really appreciate your suggestions:

My use case: I have two airflow DAGs

1. daily schedule DAG1 taskA -> taskB (daily run at 5AM)
2. hourly schedule DAG2 taskX -> taskY (every hourly run at 15th minute)

Now, I need to orchestrate  DAG1 taskB  to depend on DAG2 taskY. In other words, [DAG1 taskA, DAG2 taskY] -> DAG1 taskB

Is there a good way to implement this in airflow?

Comment: We're missing some information to answer you. Which hourly start_date is supposed to be waited by your daily task ? What's the rule you want to enforce ?

Comment: update the example scheduling for daily and hourly DAGs. (5AM for daily, 15th minute every hour for example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/)'s `ExternalTaskSensor` to handle cross-DAG dependencies.
The [`ExternalTaskSensor`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.3/_api/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor/index.html?highlight=externaltasksensor#airflow.sensors.external_task_sensor.ExternalTaskSensor) pauses until a task in another [DAG](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.3/concepts.html#dags) has completed.

If you want to run DAG1's `taskB` only if DAG2's `taskY` from the previous hour has succeeded. You can set up an `ExternalTaskSensor` in DAG1 that waits for `taskY` in DAG2 to finish.

For instance:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.sensors.external_task_sensor import ExternalTaskSensor

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 7, 7),
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag1 = DAG(
    'dag1',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='0 5 * * *'  # daily run at 5AM
)

dag2 = DAG(
    'dag2',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='15 * * * *'  # every hourly run at 15th minute
)

# DAG1
taskA_dag1 = DummyOperator(task_id='taskA', dag=dag1)

wait_for_taskY_dag2 = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='wait_for_taskY_dag2',
    external_dag_id='dag2',
    external_task_id='taskY',
    allowed_states=['success'],
    execution_delta=timedelta(hours=1),  # depends on the time difference between DAG1 and DAG2 schedule
    dag=dag1
)

taskB_dag1 = DummyOperator(task_id='taskB', dag=dag1)

taskA_dag1 >> wait_for_taskY_dag2 >> taskB_dag1

# DAG2
taskX_dag2 = DummyOperator(task_id='taskX', dag=dag2)
taskY_dag2 = DummyOperator(task_id='taskY', dag=dag2)

taskX_dag2 >> taskY_dag2
```

In that example, `taskA` and `wait_for_taskY_dag2` are independent tasks in DAG1 and can run in parallel. Once `taskA` finishes and `wait_for_taskY_dag2` senses that `taskY` from DAG2 has succeeded, `taskB` in DAG1 can run.

The `execution_delta` argument in the `ExternalTaskSensor` operator allows you to account for the difference in schedule between the two DAGs.

Warning: `ExternalTaskSensor` could keep your tasks in the running state for an extended period of time if the external task it is waiting for takes long to complete or if the `execution_delta` is large. That could lead to unnecessary resource consumption. Always ensure your Airflow setup has the necessary resources to handle these cases.

And remember that cross-DAG dependencies can make your workflows harder to manage and reason about, especially as the number of DAGs and dependencies grows. Always consider if such dependencies are necessary or if tasks could be restructured into a single DAG.
This solution works for a simple graph.